# How can I access my DataBase (using a context) with my class (which is not an activity)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android Developement and to Java too. I am working on a search tool. I have a SQLite database and the search tool search in it with success. Now I want to use custom suggestions.

The problem is : I want to access my database inside my SearchSuggestionsProvider but can't because i need a context (and the class is not an Activity).

I read that i could pass a context in the constructor but since i'm not creating any objects I can't. Maybe I'm missing something here.

I followed this tutorial : http://weblog.plexobject.com/?p=1689.

Here is my SearchSuggestionsProvider class :

```
public class SearchSuggestionsProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    static final String TAG = SearchSuggestionsProvider.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String AUTHORITY = SearchSuggestionsProvider.class
            .getName();
    public static final int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES | DATABASE_MODE_2LINES;
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {
            "_id", // must include this column
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID };

public SearchSuggestionsProvider() {
    setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    String query = selectionArgs[0];
    if (query == null || query.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);

    try {
        List<Pokemon> list = callmyservice(query);
        int n = 0;
        for (Pokemon pokemon : list) {
            cursor.addRow(createRow(new Integer(n), query, pokemon.getName(),
                    pokemon.getTier()));
            n++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to lookup " + query, e);
    }
    return cursor;
}

private Object[] createRow(Integer id, String text1, String text2,
                           String name) {
    return new Object[] { id, // _id
            text1, // text1
            text2, // text2
            text1, "android.intent.action.SEARCH", // action
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT };
}
```

(I didn't show the delete, insert, update function, which throw exceptions anyway)
The only think I have to do is to create mt own "callmyservice" function. This is where I want to access my database.

How can I do this ?

PS : Yes i'm dealing with a Pokemon Application ;D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#getContext()) inside of your `SearchSuggestionProvider` class.

Your class extends [SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.html) which extends [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) and has the method `getContext()`.

When you call `callmyservice` to pull database results, make sure to pass in `getContext()` to use that with your database.

```
Context context = getContext();
List<Pokemon> list = callmyservice(context, query);
```

Alternatively you can use a reference to an **application** context within your database classes instead, depending on your code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Though the working class is not activity, you must have at least a single activity class. Right? So in the activity class create a getter.

```
public Context getContext(){
return mContext;
}
```

For which you must have a **mContext** field in the activity class that should be initialized to refer to activity's context.

```
mContext = getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: I have my MainActivity who can handle this job. But I need to create an instance of the MainActivity class to use this getter right ? Isn't it a bit problematic ?